# Insert and execute code on existing PDF files

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, tin-can-api

I have learned about Tin Can API and it said it can track almost all learning activities including reading a PDF file, so does anybody know how to do that?

Is there a way to insert some code (maybe JavaScript or C#) which then send xAPI Statement to LRS?

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite legal, at least it's not recommended to execute a file when you should just read it

Comment: so what should I do?
embed pdf to html page and execute javascript to send xAPI statement from there?

Comment: This is a known attack vector for malware so even if you make it work today you might find it unusable tomorrow.  This is not the place to get advice for code-injection, alas.

Comment: hmm, thank you for your explaination, so the best thing to do is maybe build a mobile app for pdf reader and embed code on there to communicate with LRS and sending Tin Can Statement, am I right?

Comment: Look up the PeBL project (https://peblproject.com/getStarted.html) as this is part of what they are doing. This may be of some help

Answer (score 0):

On one hand you need an LRS server to keep a repository of actions performed by the user (yours or some other institution's).  On the other you need to serve the pdf with something that'll handle the xAPI protocol.  I know links are not cool in general :-), but this is the one you need https://xapi.com/  You're basically zipping some json files with your pdf/content and that makes an xAPI-enabled package, which you can then serve through an LMS or just distribute.